# How can i integrate sparkle updater framework with my python application built with pyinstaller

Tags: python, auto-update, sparkle

We are developing a python application which will be installed as a process on mac (There is no UI for this app, It just installs and starts the process).
I came across [sparkle framework](https://sparkle-project.org/documentation/) which is used by most of the apps on mac for auto updates.

But i see that the framework is written in C. The distributable that we give the customers is a mpkg.
Is there any way to update the application with sparkle  by integrating it in python application?

Are there any alternatives that i can look for?
Is it possible to write a separate updater application in xcode that will update my app (python app)?